# Why doesn't the clipboard work in modern linux distributions?

Tags: window-manager, clipboard, system-requirements

Can't the developers finally in 2011 move away from the flawed concepts of selections and private clipboards in applications and create a working clipboard service under X window system?

I'm terribly frustrated because of losing my content after closing applications, because of weird middle button behaviour and for other cases of inferiority of Linux clipboard when compared to Mac OS X or Windows.

Neither Glipper, Klipper, nor xfce4-clipman can heal my wounds.

Comment: i share your feelings. it is the mixture of clipboard and primary and secondary selections that cause problems and confusions.

Comment: This question isn't really answerable -- software has bugs and most of those bugs are filed, they just haven't been fixed.

Comment: -1 not an objective questions

Comment: Please elaborate the question please.

Answer (score 2):

There are also long-time X users who consider the Mac OS X & Windows clipboard functionality broken, so this is partially just about what you have been used to.

A clipboard manager should solve most of your issues, and where not, you might want to write documentation or file bug reports about what exactly is lacking (use cases that fail), so that the authors of those programs can know what features might be useful.  (In any case, a "better" solution would probably require zero changes to the clipboard itself, but instead changes to applications & maybe clipboard managers...)

BTW: the situation on Windows isn't "perfect" either, as for most programs the clipboard manager also has less (or sometimes even no) useful data after closing the application than while it's still running.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same frustrations before I installed Parcellite.

I don't see the need to develop yet another clipboard manager. Instead I think it would be great to have one preinstalled.

Comment: +1 Parcellite is awesome and solves a lot of problems. KDE has a cliboard manager (klipper) installed and started by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have many problems with Ubuntu's default clipboard behavior.  The only issue is when using rdesktop, sometimes I can't copy and paste from the remote desktop to the local machine until restarting the rdesktop connection.  As a rule of thumb though, never trust the clipboard for anything important... always keep the original open until you're sure you don't need it anymore.